# Trying to find a way to create sample data with random address in spain

Tags: python, generator

I've been trying to create some sample data for a project and I can't seem to find a way to create fake addresses in Spain.

I've tried the faker module but it doesn't really give correct addresses, I need the zip code and the city to match and faker doesn't check that at all. I've thought of using geopy but I would kinda need to apply a bias in the locations so there's more density in big cities.

Does anyone know of a simpler way of getting this type of data?

Or can someone please help me out with how to code that?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Here you can have a list of addresses, but it's only from sant Boi de Llobregat  https://datos.gob.es/en/catalogo/l01082009-direcciones-postales

Comment: I found this: https://randommer.io/random-address, there you can generate up to 1000 addresses in csv style. Maybe this works. I did not confirm that the addresses exist, but at least the city parts seem reasonable.